# how can we get country name through ip address using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me to find the country name through ip address using jquery or JavaScript.

I am using this code for getting the ip address. But I am not getting any idea how can we get the country name using the IP Address. Please help me.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
     alert("Your ip: " + data.ip);
 });
</script>
```

Please help me

Comment: You need to use a third party service, such as http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p26uE/1/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a service that actually returns countrynames, like FreeGeoIp

```
$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
    var country = data.country_name;
    var ip = data.ip;
});
```

Comment: As of today, http://freegeoip.net/json/ has been deprecated

Comment: Hello adeneo, This is not working for now. can you please help me why this is not working

Comment: As the link above states, the FreeGeoIP API has been deprecated, but they do offer a drop in replacement that requires you to sign up